# Box-shadow inset & border:none cause form fields to flicker in IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem on IE/Edge. I tried to solve it a couple day ago but I have no ideas. As I scrolled up and down my website, the form fields were flickering and flashing with white, grey and blue colors. I found out the issue, it was the `box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15) and border:0;` . If I removed the `inset` attribute in `box-shadow` or `border:0` in those input fields, then the form fields went back to the normal behavior. However, I want to keep those in the website. Not sure if there is any ways to work around this.

I attached the screenshot here
[image: Form fields flickering sample 1]

[image: Form fields flickering sample 2]

Codes:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"] {
    height: 4.2rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 40rem;
    background: $color_light_grey_1;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: spacing(xxs) spacing(xs);
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s, border-width 0.2s;
    border-left: 0 solid var(--color-primary);

    &:focus {
        outline: 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        border-left-width: 3px;
    }

    @include breakpoint(xs) {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        padding: spacing(xxs) spacing(sm);
    }

    &.input--alternate {
        background: $color_white;
        box-shadow: $light_shadow;

        &:focus {
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px $color_medium_grey_1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait until Edge is just Chrome? If you can't wait, then show your research. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45826245/1531971 (or tell us why this does not apply to you.)

Comment: I did some research but they are all related to css transform animation, but in my form fields I did not use any transform property. The problem with mine is that if I removed the border:0; property or box-shadow:inset; everything will be fine. However, I needs those properties for my form fields @jdv

Comment: You should _show_ your research. Don't put content in comments; Q&A should be stand-alone.

Answer (score 0):

In IE a property `border-collapse: collapse;` gets added automatically. try adding 'border-collapse: separate; to your input class.

Comment: I tried to add the border-collapse: seperate;, but the form fields are still flickering